# jQuery/JavaScript output in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery code that is supposed to insert some content after every paragraph on news articles. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("<a>The link inserted in jQuery</a>")
        .insertAfter("p")
        .attr("href", "http://bi.ng")
        .addClass("abonnerreklame")
    ;
});
```

It works in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKxg9/) that I've made, but not on my actual site. The reason behind that, have to be that the articles use dynamic PHP to render (WordPress):

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Is there a way to get the JavaScript to work, even when the output is generated from PHP? I hope you can understand my question - please help if you have the knowledge to do so.

[Here](http://dansas.no) is my test site, by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: you should fix error firstly, check your console

Comment: I got this in IE, but I don't know what it means: `SCRIPT5007: Expected an object - File: dansas.no, Line: 47, Column: 1`

Comment: In Chrome the console says it doesn't recognize the $ used by jQuery, thus stopping the excecution of the JS. When you've fixed your JS, it will work. As @anthonybell says, for the browser it is static content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change $ by jQuery. it Will work. Check your console and you will see an error about '$'.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("<a>The link inserted in jQuery</a>")
        .insertAfter("p")
        .attr("href", "http://bi.ng")
        .addClass("abonnerreklame")
    ;
});
```

This is because in the actual site, jQuery is in no-conflict mode, and it changes '$' with 'jQuery', because other frameworks (as Mootools) can use also '$'

Comment: Thank you so much! I am just a newbie in JavaScript/jQuery, would never have figured out that by myself - and I didn't find an already existing question regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Php is not dynamic.  The content generated by a php script is static as far as the browser is concerned.  When the content is served to the client, the client cannot tell the difference between content generated by a php script and static content.  Since javascript only runs on the client, the same is true regarding javascript

Comment: you should have put this as a comment since this is not an answer to his question.

Comment: @anthonybell Thanks for clearing that up. I'm aware that I am not always using the correct words regarding PHP/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you provided, it looks like '$' is not defined properly or has been altered to suit wordpress noconflict.